# Stream from Mac to Samsung UN32J5205AFXZA

Tags: macbook-pro, streaming, vlc

**Environment**

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011) OS X 10.10.5
- Samsung TV UN32J5205AFXZA
- Both devices working on a 1,000 Mbps home network

**Problem**

I am trying to stream video from the Mac to the TV but have not been successful yet.

**Attempts**

My first attempt used VLC (version 2.2.1) on the Mac to stream a video to the TV. I followed [these instructions](http://www.wondershare.com/vlc/stream-vlc-to-tv.html). Then on the TV, according to the user manual, I should go to *Network > Multimedia Device Settings* and see the Mac listed there. The list is empty though. The video being streamed is in .mp4 format. According to the TV user manual, that format is supported.

**Questions**

1. How do I make VLC stream video to the TV?
2. If VLC cannot do it, which other free options can?

Comment: You're better off using third party applications such as Plex Media Server. You'd think it should be quite straightforward by the end of first half of second decade of second millennia, but it's not...

Comment: @user14492 - grumble cakes. Not what I like hearing :(  Any idea *why* VLC can't make it happen?

Comment: Closely related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-can-i-make-my-mac-a-dlna-server-and-or-client

Comment: Wondershare (the site you linked in your question) is probably not the best place to look for VLC instructions (their primary goal is to pitch their own products). Did you check out https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the recommendations and troubleshooting tips. Eventually I ended up using [Universal Media Server](http://www.universalmediaserver.com). It's been working well so far, and it's free.